# matcher GMS opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'd like to find the corresponding points on the frames using the gms matcher(https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/db/dd9/group__xfeatures2d__match.html). So I write:

```
import copy
import cv2
from cv2.xfeatures2d import matchGMS

def match(img1, img2):
    kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
    kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2, None)
    matcher = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING)
    matches_all = matcher.match(des1, des2)
    matches_gms = matchGMS(img1.shape, img2.shape, kp1, kp2, matches_all)
    return matches_gms

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path_to_video)
frame1 = None
frame2 = None
while(cap.isOpened()):    
    state, frame2 = cap.read()
    frame2 = cv2.cvtColor(frame2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    matches_gms = []
    if frame1 is not None:   
        matches_gms = match(frame1, frame2)
    frame1 = copy.copy(frame2)

cap.release()
```

But when I call the second time `match(frame1, frame2)`, I get an error `'cv2.DMatch' object is not callable`. What should I do?

Comment: Please, include the full error message (including the full backtrace). Futhermore, your code fails to verify whether `cap.read()` succeeded and uses the (potentially empty) frame anyway. | Also, why `copy.copy(frame2)` instead of a simple `frame2.copy()`?

Comment: This is all that Jupyter produced as error output. I try different solutions to get full stack trace, but nothing help me. Do you know how to get full stack trace?

Comment: It's been a while since I've used Jupyter... can you run it in the command line Python interpreter? In the current code, as you show it, I'm having a hard time seeing why you'd get that error.... well other than the things I've mentioned. | Also, keep in mind that `cap.isOpened()` returns `True` even after you reached the end of the file, so this use is a bit misleading.

Comment: Thanks. How best to use 'while' with 'cap.read()'?

Comment: Something like [this](https://pastebin.com/7z3zcpfJ) perhaps? :) Right after opening a video, you test once whether you successfully opened it, and then in each iteration you test whether the `read` succeeded -- if not, that's the end of the file, and you `break` out of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution : just rename `match` function. 
With `match` name first iteration is working correctly, but on second iteration `match` is not my function (smth rewrote my object) and invocation of `match` method failed.